# Can I marry my mother's maternal uncle's daughter?

Tags: nikah, relationships

Can I marry my mother's maternal uncle's daughter? whom I love very much.

Comment: We seem to get some relish downvoting perfectly valid questions!

Answer (score 1):

Since you can marry your *own* maternal uncle daughter (that would be your cousin), you can marry your mother maternal uncle daughter as well. Cousins are not considered brother and sisters in islam. If she is your mother cousin, you can marry her.